# How to display default 1st value from controller to my page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

There are 2 custom objects here Topic and task.
Topic here displays the related topics and on click of particular topic its related task is displayed. 
What i need is to display the 1st topic records ie tasks by default . how do i do it..

**VF page**

```
       <apex:dataList value="{!mytopics}" var="topi" style="margin-top:0px; list-style-type: none; " >
                <apex:commandLink action="{!Topic_clicked}" value="{!topi.name}"   styleClass="font" reRender="Output_block"  >
                    <apex:param value="{!topi.id}" name="ID" assignTo="{!selected_topicID}"/>
                </apex:commandLink>

<apex:outputPanel id="Output_block"  >
<apex:repeat value="{!taskinfo}" var="tasks"  >
<h6>{!tasks.name}</h6>
<p >--------------------------------------------------------------</P><br/><br/>
<apex:repeat value="{!tasks.tasks__r}" var="tsk"   >
{!tsk.id}
<!-- <h1>Topic :</h1> {!tsk.Topic__c} <br/> -->
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!tsk.Session_Details__c!=null}"><h1>Session Type:</h1>  {!tsk.Session_Details__c}</apex:outputPanel><br/>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!tsk.Description__c !=null}"><h1> Course Content  :</h1>   {!tsk.Description__c } </apex:outputPanel><br/>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!tsk.Solution_Content__c!=null}"><h1> Trainer Assignment :</h1>   {!tsk.Solution_Content__c}</apex:outputPanel><br/>

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!tsk.SAXON_ASSIGNMENTS__c!=null}"><h1>Saxon Assignment:</h1>    {!tsk.SAXON_ASSIGNMENTS__c} <br/></apex:outputPanel>

<HR></HR>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

**Controller**

```
public class controller_topics {

    public List<topic__c> getMytopics() {
        return [select name from topic__c];
    }
     public List<topic__c> taskinfo {get; set;}

     public  Id selected_topicID { get;set; } 

    Public void Topic_clicked(){
    taskinfo = [select name ,(select Topic__c,Session_Details__c,SAXON_ASSIGNMENTS__c,Solution_Content__c,Description__c from tasks__r ) from topic__c where id =: selected_topicID ];

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimum change is probably to do the pre-selection in a constructor added to the controller:

```
public class controller_topics {
    public controller_topics() {
        List<topic__c> topics = getMytopics();
        if (topics.size() > 0) {
            selected_topicID = topics[0].Id;
            Topic_clicked();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```